# How to define global variables in groovy file, which I want to load and consume?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, groovy, environment-variables

I have a Jenkins parent groovy file which consumes the child groovy file

**Parent grooy file:**

```
...
def child = load 'child-groovy-file';
child.execute();
```

**Child groovy file:**

```
a = "first letter";
b = "second letter;
def execute
{
echo "a is "+a;
...
}
```

> But this is not working. Unable to access variables, which are defined
>   in Child Groovy file, when trying to access from Parent groovy file.
>   When I create a node block and trying to consume directly the child
>   groovy file, It is working.

Is the Environment variables only the solution to access globally?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
static void main(String[] args) { 
      // Initializing 2 variables 
      def x = 5; 
      def y = 10;

      //Performing addition of 2 operands 
      println(x+y);
 }
```

}

check this [URL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_arithmetic_operators.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It just could be that:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field public a = "first letter"
@Field public b = "second letter"
```

works (I got hint from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/)

When referencing (environment variables) I saw the format did not exactly
work, but the following did:

```
@Field public c; c = 'prefix ' + VAR + ' suffix'
```

(probably "prefix ${VAR} suffix" worked but did not try that (either))

Answer (score 0):

Your example code has a typo: `b = "second letter;` is missing the closing quote. Even if you fix that typo your code still won't work.

If you print the `child` variable it will be `null`?

That is because you are missing `return this` at the bottom of `child-groovy-file`.

It's mentioned in the Jenkins [load](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/) documentation:

> Where `pipeline.groovy` defines `functionA` and `functionB` functions (among
> others) before ending with `return this`;

I fixed your code and ran this POC:

[image: Example code]

This resulted in:

[image: results of example code]

While loading scripts like this might have some use cases, they are not very common.  If you are looking to have reusable code you should use Jenkins [Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) feature. If you want to see an example of what can be done with a shared-library see [The Jenkins Standard Library](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/jenkins-std-lib), which can do things like run Github Actions! I also happen to be the author of that library.